# AWS - S3 - GetBucketPolicy

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Having trouble understanding just why my get_bucket_policy function is not working. i have double checked for typos and I have a policy and I get this error:

```
An error occurred (NoSuchBucketPolicy) when calling the GetBucketPolicy operation: The bucket policy does not exist
```

from this script:

```
import boto3
import json

BUCKET_NAME ='patrick-s3-2018-bucket'

def s3_client():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    """:type : pyboto3.s3"""
    return s3

def create_bucket(bucket_name):
    return s3_client().create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={
            'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'
            }
        )

def create_bucket_policy():
    bucket_policy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement":[
            {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action":["s3:*"],
            "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::patricksbucket/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
    policy_string = json.dumps(bucket_policy)

    return s3_client().put_bucket_policy(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Policy=policy_string
    )
def list_buckets():
    return s3_client().list_buckets()

def get_bucket_policy():
    return s3_client().get_bucket_policy(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_bucket_policy())
```

I have also tried to use the full actual bucket name , not just the variable but this has not solved the issue.

This issue does not appear to be well documented online, when using AWS resources it is hard for me to compare their examples to the UDEMY class example I am using as I am still learning

Comment: Does your bucket *have* a policy?  The error message suggests that it does not.

Comment: so actually my "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::patricksbucket/*"]  , was different than BUCKET_NAME ='patrick-s3-2018-bucket'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Answer to my own questions:

First error:  my `"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::patricksbucket/*"]`  , was different than `BUCKET_NAME ='patrick-s3-2018-bucket'`
Second Error: I needed to `create_bucket`